# joining the ADASYN balanced features and target label

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to balance my highly imbalanced data using ADASYN library. 
After I balance my data I have to join the features and target label numpy arrays into one single data frame.

Here is my Python code for balancing data:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import ADASYN
ada = ADASYN()
# X is feature set and y is the label
X_resampled, y_resampled = ada.fit_sample(X, y)
# Add X_resampled, y_resampled into one dataframe
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Maybe `df = pd.concat([X_resampled, y_resampled], axis=1)`?

Comment: I get an error - TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: Then how about `df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((X_resampled, y_resampled)))`?

Comment: Still get an error. ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions. Shape of XSampled is (279, 145) and ySampled is (279,)

Comment: ok, then `df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((X_resampled, y_resampled.reshape(-1, 1))))`

Comment: That worked. Can you please add this as an answer?

Comment: Glad to hear and sure thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X_resampled` and `y_resampled` are numpy arrays, so we'll need to `np.hstack` (horizontally stack) them in the solution.

`X_resampled` is 2D, but `y_resampled` is 1D. Before `np.hstack`, we need to reshape `y_resampled` into a 2D array with one column.

All together:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((X_resampled, y_resampled.reshape(-1, 1))))
```